# Conditional probability given conditional probabilities

Tags: self-study, random-variable, conditional-probability, independence, hypergeometric-distribution

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent binomial random variables with identical parameters $n$ and $p$, show
analytically that the conditional probability of $X$, given that $X + Y = m$ is the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. What have you tried so far?